# Why figures are not being pulled into pdf from R markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I'm using RStudio and knitr to create reproducable PDF reports on work. However, figures are not pulled into the document - instead there is "figure/unnamed-chunk-" where the image should be.
Images are produced and saved to 'home/figure/'.
The code I use to create the PDF is:

```
Rfile = "/Users/user/Documents/folder/file.R"
setwd(dirname(Rfile))
spin(Rfile, format = 'Rmd', report=F)
render(paste(substring(Rfile,0,(nchar(file)-1)),"md",sep=""), pdf_document(toc = TRUE, toc_depth=6, number_sections= TRUE), 
       output_file = paste(substring(file,0,(nchar(file)-2)),".pdf",sep=""))
```

In the md file, there is a line for each figure that is

```
figure/unnamed-chunk-X-X.pdf
```

I've tried adding the lines below after reading the answers at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/_sw4sAtLkoQ - but they don't make a difference.

```
opts_knit$set(base.dir = dirname(file)) 
opts_knit$set(fig.path = '/figure/')
```

I'm sure there is a simple fix to this but I can't see what it might be.

Comment: What happens if you spin and then use the Knitr button on the output file?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what is the 'knitr button'?

Comment: When you open a `.Rmd` file in Rstudio there are some new buttons in the editor window. One of them is **Knit** that runs `knitr` to creat the output file (HTML, PDF or Word). I was wondering if it worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Unfortunately, same result.